# how can i access private member += function in c++

Tags: c++

I learning c++ language to my currier.
The thing i have a question is how can i access private member value below code.

```
Fraction& operator+= (const Fraction& right);
Fraction& Fraction::operator+=(const Fraction& right)
{
    numer = numer * right.denom + right.numer * denom;
    denom = denom * right.denom;
    normalize();
    return *this;
}
```

i did not use a friend function but i can use right.denom and right.numer which is private member.

```
    class Fraction
{
private:
    int numer;
    int denom;
```

but when i use a another code. there always need to be friend function when i use private member.

```
friend const Fraction operator+(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right);
const Fraction operator+(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right)
{
    int newNumer = left.numer * right.denom + right.numer * left.denom;
    int newDenom = left.denom * right.denom;
    Fraction result(newNumer, newDenom);
    return result;
}
```

Compile error occured when i deleted a friend. What difference operator+= and operator+

If somebody know. Please Let me know to answer

Comment: Normally you can access private members only from public members or `friend`s.

Comment: Assuming `Fraction& operator+= (const Fraction& right);` is embedded in the class declaration, then it is a class method which is perrmitted to operate on its all members. All other functions declared outside the class have access only to the public fields (unless they were marked as a `friend` **inside** the class declaration).

Comment: You can change the function to: `const Fraction operator+(Fraction left, const Fraction& right) { return left += right; }`. Note that `left` is passed by value. Then you do not need to declare this function as `friend`.

Comment: @kiner_shah --  access controls do not affect access from member functions; **all** members have access to **all** members.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yeah you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `private` scope in C++ prevents access from outside. It does not prevent access from objects of the same class. Therefore, the objects instantiated from  `class Fraction` can access each other attribute without any prevention.

When you write

```
Fraction a, b;
a += b;
```

It is equivalent as

```
Fraction a, b;
a.operator+=(b);
```

Therefore, object a can access attributes of object b easily. However, when you write

```
Fraction a, b;
Fraction c = a + b;
```

It is equivalent to

```
Fraction a, b;
Fraction c = operator+(a, b);
```

Now, the operator is not the member function of object a, so, it cannot access attributes of object b since it is not accessing on behalf of object a anymore